# Sinatra Static Page

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In my public folder, I have a file *index.html*. I want to be able to just use the url *localhost:4567* to display the page (without displaying *localhost:4567/index.html*)

This is my current ruby script:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :public_folder, 'public'

get '/' do
  redirect '/index.html'
end
```

I have tried removing the redirect statement, but the url still comes up with the *index.html*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`send_file`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sending%20Files) here:

```
get "/" do
  send_file 'public/index.html'
end
```

You need to provide the full path of the file from the working directory (i.e. not just the path under `public`), and this only works at the root url, it won’t serve `index.html` pages for directories generally. If you want that you would probably need to set up a separate web server in front of Sinatra and configure it appropriately.

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thank so much

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind redirects is exactly to force the browser make a new request to where you are redirecting to.
As you don't want to change the url, you have two possible solutions:

1. Rewrite instead of redirect. Sinatra itself doesn't provide such functionality, but you can easily use a rack middleware:

   ```
   require 'rack/rewrite'

   use Rack::Rewrite do
     rewrite '/', '/index.html'
   end
   ```
2. Serve the *index.html* contents when asked for the root path:

   ```
   get '/' do
     File.read("#{APP_ROOT}/public/index.html")
   end
   ```

Comment: @matt's way of serving files is better.